# command not found even though it's on the path

Tags: software-installation, path

I've read most of the posts on this topic but no luck so far.

```
:$ echo $PATH

/home/eoan/bin/firefox-dev/:/home/eoan/bin/Telegram/:/home/eoan/.local/share/umake/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin
```

The executables under firefox or telegram directories run if I just type the path on the console, do not run otherwise.

I've `source  ~/.bashrc`, make sure they are with the right privileges, `hash -r` etc.. But nothing seems to work.

Any ideas please?

**EDIT**

Running `ls -l` it outputs

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 eoan eoan 101222968 Jun 23 20:50 Telegram
-rw-r--r-- 1 eoan eoan   1390581 Jun 23 20:07 Updater
-rwxrwxrwx 1 eoan eoan    622400 Jul 13 09:20 firefox-bin
```

**EDIT2**

`which firefox-bin`

returned

```
/home/eoan/bin/firefox-dev//firefox-bin
```

I removed the end-slash for FF on the `$PATH`. Same for all the remaining directories. Finally, changed privileges on Telegram. Now both run. Thx Eduardo.

Comment: Is that the actual output from `echo $PATH`? Please don't redact it. Also, could you add the output you get when you try to run, say, Telegram? And an `ls -l /home/eoan/bin/Telegram/program_you_want_to_run`?

Comment: bin/Telegram? firefox/telegram? These are different paths.  Which is right?

Comment: @stolenmoment sorry. edited

Comment: @EduardoTrápani edited. The path is the output, I just press enter in the post to avoid the overflow-x behaviour.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, we can scroll to see the rest. In the future try to leave everything as-is.  For example, end of line is a valid character, and if you had it in your path you would not find the directories. Also, when including output, also include the actual command (the `ls` above). Each modification or missing part makes it harder for those trying to help.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani that makes sense. Thanks. I'll update. Even then this never happened to me before :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have more or less your setup.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/user/bin/Telegram
```

and

```
$ ls -l /home/user/bin/Telegram/Telegram 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 101222968 jun 30 12:29
```

You can check if your path is ok by issuing the command `which`, will will tell you how a pathless command was resolved:

```
$ which Telegram
/home/user/bin/Telegram/Telegram
```

Now, if I run just `Telegram` it will be found and run. Could you check if the commands above return similar results?

Comment: My god, it's working now. When I run `which X` for X=firefox-bin it returned an extra slash in the name, and nothing for Telegram. Once I removed the end-slashes in the $PATH for each one, and run chmod  777 in Telegram's folder, It went fine. I will update the post so you can provide  a complete answer

Comment: `777` is asking for trouble. Also use symbolic mode. I hear it is available on all modern `chmod`s.